# sklearn - How to reload model with a pipeline and predict?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I've saved a trained model and the testing dataset and wish to reload it just to verify I'm getting the same results for future use of the model (I don't have new data to test on at the moment). The csv I've saved does not contain the labels, it's the same test data as in the original train/test operation which worked fine.

I created the model like so:

```
# copy split data for this model
dtc_test_X = test_X
dtc_test_y = test_y
dtc_train_X = train_X
dtc_train_y = train_y

# initialize the model
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 1)
# fit the trianing data
dtc_yhat = dtc.fit(dtc_train_X, dtc_train_y).predict(dtc_test_X)
# scikit-learn's accuracy scoring
acc = accuracy_score(dtc_test_y, dtc_yhat)
# scikit-learn's Jaccard Index
jacc = jaccard_similarity_score(dtc_test_y, dtc_yhat)
# scikit-learn's classification report
class_report = classification_report(dtc_test_y, dtc_yhat)
```

I've saved the model and data below:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.externals import joblib

# setup the pipe line
pipe = make_pipeline(DecisionTreeClassifier)
# save the model
joblib.dump(pipe, 'model.pkl')
dtc_test_X.to_csv('set_to_predict.csv')
```

When I reload the model and attempt a prediction as follows:

```
#Loading the saved model with joblib
pipe = joblib.load('model.pkl')

# New data to predict
pr = pd.read_csv('set_to_predict.csv')
pred_cols = list(pr.columns.values)
pred_cols
# apply the whole pipeline to data
pred = pd.Series(pipe.predict(pr[pred_cols]))
```

On the last line though (the prediction) it raised an exception:

```
TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

Searching for an answer, I can only find examples of a similar exception but with `Y` instead of `X` and the answers don't seem to apply. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `pipe.predict(pr[pred_cols])` by `pipe.predict(X=pr[pred_cols])` to see if it works or if it drops you other error